# Calling correct Function

Tags: python

I have below code :

```
def pStockName():

        global StockList,fStockList
        fStockList = []
        pStockList = []
        StockList = str(raw_input('Enter pipe separated list of StockS : ')).upper().strip()
        items = StockList.split("|")
        count = len(items)
        print  'Total Distint Stock Count : ',  count
        items = list(set(StockList.split("|")))
        pipelst = [i.replace('-mc','').replace('-MC','').replace('$','').replace('^','') for i in items]
        filepath = '/fsnadmin/SAAS_SUPPORT/Stock_data.txt'
        f = open(filepath, 'r')
        for lns in f:
                split_pipe = lns.split(':', 1)
                if split_pipe[0] in pipelst:
                        index = pipelst.index(split_pipe[0])
                        pStockList=split_pipe[0]+"|"
                        fStockList.append(pStockList)
                        del pipelst[index]

        for lns in pipelst:
                print bcolors.red + lns,' is not found in SaaS Stock Inventory' + bcolors.ENDC
         if pipelst:
        #if not lns:
                uResp = str(raw_input('Do You Want To Continue with option 0 [YES|Y|NO|N] : ')).upper().strip()
                if uResp == "YES" or uResp == "Y":
                        pStockName ()
                else:
                        #StockList = None
                        print_menu ()
        f.close()
```

When I execute this code, it prompts me to write the list of stocks and if I give all correct stocks (mentioned in /location/stock_data.txt, calling in above code) it execute correctly as below :

> Enter pipe separated list of StockS : aaa|hfa|fff
>
> Total Distint Stock Count :  3
>
> Stocks Belonging to other Centers :
>
> Stock Count From Other =  0
>
> Stocks Belonging to Current Centers :
>
> Active Stocks in  US1:
>
> ^AAA$|^HFA$
>
> Terminated Stocks in  US2:
>
> ^FFF$
>
> Ignored Stock Count From Current Center =  1
>
> You Have Entered StockList belonging to this center as: ^AAA$|^HFA$
>
> Active Stock Count :  2
>
> Do You Want To Continue [YES|Y|NO|N] :

and if give all wrong stock (if not available in /location/stock_data.txt file) and execute above code it gives the result like below:

> Enter your choice [0-26] : 0
>
> Enter pipe separated list of StockS : jjj|uuu|oo
>
> Total Distint Stock Count :  3
>
> UUU  is not found in Stock list
>
> OO  is not found in Stock
>
> JJJ  is not found in Stock
>
> Do You Want To Continue with option 0 [YES|Y|NO|N] : Y
>
> Enter pipe separated list of stocks :

So far I am getting the result as I needed. But if I give any wrong stock in between of the right stock its not asking again for enter separated list of StockS though it executes like below :

> Enter pipe separated list of StockS : aaa|hfa|ooo
>
> Total Distint Stock Count :  3
>
> OOO  is not found in  Stock list
>
> Stocks Belonging to other Data Centers :
>
> Stock Count From Other centers =  0
>
> Stocks Belonging to Current Data Centers :
>
> Active Stocks in  US1 :
>
> ^AAA$|^HFA$
>
> Ignored Stock Count From Current center =  0
>
> You Have Entered StockList belonging to this center as: ^AAA$|^HFA$
>
> Active Stock Count :  2
>
> Do You Want To Continue [YES|Y|NO|N] :

As you are seeing in above statement in above statement I am getting wrong stock information (OOO  is not found in  Stock list) after that code is executing with the right stock. 
What I want is if I give any of the wrong stock it should not continue with after giving the wrong stock information and right after that it should again ask for Enter pipe separated list of stocks after giving the option Y(yes), just as like I am getting the statement when I give all wrong stocks.

Please let me know how can I achieve this.

Please have a look in below execution

> Enter your choice [0-26] : 0
>
> Enter pipe separated list of StockS : aaa|hfa|kk
>
> Total Distint Stock Count :  3
>
> KK  is not found in  Stock Inventory
>
> Do You Want To Continue with option 0 [YES|Y|NO|N] : Y
>
> Enter pipe separated list of StockS : aaa|hfa
>
> Total Distint Stock Count :  2
>
> Stocks Belonging to other Centers :
>
> Stock Count From Other center =  0
>
> Stocks Belonging to Current  Centers :
>
> Active Stocks in  US1 :
>
> ^AAA$|^HFA$
>
> Ignored Stock Count From Current center =  0
>
> You Have Entered StockList belonging to this center as: ^AAA$|^HFA$
>
> Active Stock Count :  2
>
> Do You Want To Continue [YES|Y|NO|N] : Y
>
> Stocks Belonging to other Centers :
>
> Stock Count From Other center =  0
>
> Stocks Belonging to Current Centers :
>
> Active Stocks in  US1 :
>
> ^AAA$|^HFA$
>
> Ignored Stock Count From Current center =  0
>
> You Have Entered StockList belonging to this center as: ^AAA$|^HFA$
>
> Active Stock Count :  2
>
> Do You Want To Continue [YES|Y|NO|N] :

Comment: Where is `lns` delcared for this statement: `if not lns:`?

Comment: It has the last value from the previous successful iteration.

Comment: Oh really? Didn't realize python did that

Comment: @River You are right. Now I have made the correction as if pipelst instead of if not lns . But River, Now when the prompt is asking for to enter the right stock I need to press Y(YES) twice for same information. Please have a look my last statement in my question itself after "Please let me know how can I achieve this" line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want:

```
if pipelst: #if pipelst is not empty
```

instead of

```
if not lns:
```

The first will check whether `pipelst` has elements whereas the second will do something else. (I *think* it will check whether the last element iterated in the previous `for each` statement is 0/empty, but not sure about that.)

As you want to enter this `if` whenever a single stock is invalid, and it seems that `pipelst` contains all invalid stocks at this point, checking to see if `pipelst` is empty or not seems like a good option.

Comment: You are right. Now I have made the correction as if pipelst instead of if not lns . But River, Now when the prompt is asking for to enter the right stock I need to press Y(YES) twice for same information. Please have a look my last statement in my question itself after "Please let me know how can I achieve this" line.

Comment: @Ritesh so you want it to let you enter more stocks instead of simply re-printing the same information from the current stocks? E.g. you want "Do You Want To Continue with option 0 [YES|Y|NO|N] : Y

Enter pipe separated list of StockS :" instead of "Do You Want To Continue [YES|Y|NO|N] :
<same information as before>"?

Comment: No River. Actually I have very big code. After successful list of correct stock I press yes then it'll go for the other option so that I can perform some operation with those correct stocks. But now I got the logic with your hint. Thanks so much River